# Using PGPool with RDS Slave replicas, any advice?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pgpool

I have a Postgres 9.4 RDS instance with Multi AZ, and there's a slave, read-only replica.

Up to this point the load balancing was made in the business layer of my app, but it's inneficient and I was hoping to use PGPool so the app interacts with a single postgres connection.

It turns out that using PGPool has been a pain in the ass. If I set it to act as a load balancer, simple SELECT queries throw errors like:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 
 message contents do not agree with length in message type "N" 
 server sent data ("D" message) 
 without prior row description ("T" message)
```

If I set it to act in a master / slave mode with stream replication (as [suggested in Postgres mail list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20150603.163254.1787927658853093687.t-ishii%40sraoss.co.jp)) I get:

```
psql: ERROR:  MD5 authentication is unsupported 
in replication and master-slave modes.
HINT:  check pg_hba.conf
```

Yeah, well, pg_hba.conf if off hands in RDS so I can't alter it.

If I disable master-slave behavior, I can connect using psql, but the performance is slow and the app outputs messages like

```
DEBUG:  SimpleForwardToFrontend: packet:D length:28
DEBUG:  pool_use_sync_map: we cannot use sync map because STREAM: 0 query in progress: 1 doing extended query: 0
DEBUG:  reading backend data packet kind
DETAIL:  backend:0 of 2 kind = 'D'
DEBUG:  read_kind_from_backend max_count:1.000000 num_executed_nodes:1
DEBUG:  processing backend response
DETAIL:  received kind 'D'(44) from backend
```

Is the performance slow because of the verbosity, or are those messages realing some king of configuration problem?

Has anyone got PGPool to work in RDS? Are there other tools that can act as a middleware to take advantage of read replicas in RDS?